# How to reload a div with ID xyz once the dynamic content is generated

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am creating content dynamically inside a Main div , the content is stored in another div with classes... but the content is not visible since the page and all the java scripts are already loaded ... I think I need to refresh the main div with all the classes in order for the content to be visible.....If one can please help me with the code would be great......

Sample code:

```
    <div id="grid">
--- Dynamically generated
<div class="Test" > 

</div>

    </div>
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? please provide relevant code

Comment: if I am going for a static code like below it's working fine....
"<div class="Test" > 
----abc
</div>

    </div>"   ... but when the same content is being generated dynamically by parsing rss feed and using append method it is not getting loaded ... I guess because all the java scripts related to it already loaded and hence it is not able to read it...

Comment: It will be helpful if you share more code. How are you dynamically creating the div